# Firebase functions - modify firebase functions:config programmatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am hoping to achieve to update firebase functions config (env variables) programatically other than manually typing `firebase functions:config:set` I want to automate this process depending on the returned value from a post call inside the function and possibly invoke cloud run to achieve this.

I've tried below but only worked in local env.

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {


            exec(`firebase functions:config:set hello.world="hhh"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                    return;
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            });
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'success' });

        }


    catch (e) {
        console.log('e :>> ', e);

        res.status(400).send({ status: res.statusCode, message: 'aborted' });
    }
})
```

If there's a way to achieve this, I'd like to know.

Also wondering if there's way to achieve this with cloud run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to update the environment while a function is running.  It requires a full redeploy from the CLI.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so to update configs, running script ```firebase functions:config:set``` is the only way? I'd like to automate this process of updating configs

Comment: That's the only supported way.  You can't make the change from within the function itself, unless you want to somehow reverse engineer what the CLI does, and duplicate that in your function.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I think what MK meant is if there's a way to programmatically update the firebase config file, it doesn't have to be in a function, via API or any other way so that we can automate some build flows would work, we need to programmatically update config, and then deploy the functions, Google builds does the build but updating config, we havn't found a way to do, really appreciate your help here

Comment: maybe a batch file inside your project scope could have the command `firebase functions:config:set`. I'm still trying to find a way to run this command outsite my project folder

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2022, this is actually possible, using the `firebase-functions-test` package.

For more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#mocking_config_values